# How to send push notification to a specific user using Google Firebase in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need to deliver a push notification to a specific device using FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging). How to send the notification in Objective C?

If somebody know any tutorial then give me the link.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to have device token of the user you want to send the notification to and then you can easily send user specific push notification using firebase.

Comment: when i am sending notification to single device using device token it getting sending failed how to send the notification can you explain and it showing FCM registration token what is FCM registration token ? @Himanshu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add the `pods` that you want to install, Download a `GoogleService-Info.plist` file from Firebase console.
2. Upload your APNs certificate to Firebase.
3. register your app for remote notifications. Call `registerForRemoteNotifications`.
4. Retrieve the current registration token, call:

   `NSString *refreshedToken = [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token];`
5. Finally, You use that token to send the notification from Firebase console.

For better clarification, see [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/ios/console-device)